# ESP8266Httpclient & WiFIClient(Secure) - connection fails both with HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: http, post, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to connect to a server, both using ESP8266Httpclient and WiFiClient(Secure), but no matter what I do the connection fails.

WiFiClient(Secure) version:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "wifi";
const char* password = "pass";
WiFiClientSecure client;

char server[64] = "website.domain", url[64] = "/path/to/data";


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) yield();

}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connect(server, 443)) Serial.println("Connection failed");
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection success");

  }
}
```

This always prints "Connection failed", no matter what combination I try: I tried connecting with port 80 and 443, using WiFiClient and WiFiClientSecure, adding and removing "http(s)://" from the server, they all return "Connection failed".

ESP8266Httpclient version:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "wifi"
#define STAPSK "pass"
#endif

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(STASSID, STAPSK);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected! IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    WiFiClientSecure client;
    HTTPClient http;

    Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");

    http.begin(client, "https://website.domain/path/to/data", 443);  
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    Serial.print("[HTTP] POST...\n");

    int httpCode = http.POST("{\"points\":[{\"lat\":mylat,\"lng\":mylng}],\"fuelType\":\"1-x\",\"priceOrder\":\"asc\"}");

    if (httpCode > 0) {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] POST... code: %d\n", httpCode);
      Serial.println("Redirect location: " + http.getLocation());

      //if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      const String& payload = http.getString();
      Serial.println("received payload:\n<<");
      Serial.println(payload);
      Serial.println(">>");
      //}
    } else Serial.printf("[HTTP] POST... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());

    http.end();
  }

  delay(10000);
}
```

This snippet behaves differently: if I connect to http://website.domain/path/to/data I get HTTP code 301 (moved permanently), which returns location https://website.domain/path/to/data.

If I then change the endpoint to https://website.domain/path/to/data, it returns error -1 (connection failed). I tried every combination in this code as well: port 80 and 443, with and without http(s)://, WiFiClient and WiFiClientSecure, nothing worked. I might be overlooking something very simple, or this might not be possible at all.

Comment: try to add `client.setInsecure();` for the WiFiClientSecure

Comment: I did, no change. I figured it would just be easier to use MicroPython, since it just works.

Comment: Can you connect to another domain? try this one: `https://example.com/`

Comment: It manages to connect to example.com, but still not to the website I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Juraj for the suggestion to put client.setInsecure(). I thought I'd already done that, but you actually need to call it after you create the client and before you pass it to httpclient. That way it'll actually be set as insecure. Thanks again Juraj.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).